# how to fetch radio button value in next page in radio button itself

Tags: php, html

I want to fetch the radio button values in next page in the same radio button itself. It is fetching the value but it is not fetching in radio button,When text field is given the value is displayed, but raido button is set then it is not fetching in radio button.
**here i enter the value**

```
<tr>
    <td>gender</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</td>
</tr>
```

**here i want to get the output**

```
<tr>
    <td>gender</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gender" value="<?php echo $gender ?>"/></td>
</tr>
```

friends pls share your ideas....

Comment: I dont know PHP, but  I think, you should you use a loop here.

Comment: How to use loop here?? i just want to fetch the values in radiobutton. Here in my code i displayed textbox to fetch value if i change the type into radio the value is not fetching in radio button. I am asking how to fetch the value in radio button??

Comment: look, if $gender is just a string, it will print the value of it. But it seems like, this is an Array in your condition. so you should use a look to print all the values from there. like: <?php foreach ($value as $gender)
  {?>
  <input type="text" name="gender" value="<?php echo $value ?>"/>
  <?php } ?>, something like this...

Answer (score 0):

**On the first page:**

```
<table>
    <form name="frmProfile" method="post" action="secondpage.php">
        <tr>
            <td>gender</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
    </form>     
</table>
```

**Second Page**

```
<?php
    $gender = "";
    if($_POST["gender"]) {          
        $gender = $_POST["gender"]; 
    }   
?>
<b>Second Page</b><br/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>gender</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if($gender == "female") echo "checked"; ?>>Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if($gender == "male") echo "checked"; ?>>Male
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can learn [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/examples/formex.php) more

Comment: here the values are displaying in textbox but i want to fetch in radio button. I also posted the same coding but if i change the type into radio it is not fetching the values.

Comment: @user3151593 Do you mean to say that on the next page, you want to show the selected radio option (from the first page)  as selected on the next page ?

Comment: @user3151593 I hope it worked for you. Didn't get your answer.